# An animated movie or series (anime?). A huge spaceship found in a desert and the whole of humanity is trying to fix it

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi, animation

I'm trying to find an animated film or a series which I saw once in mid/late 90s on a TV. It might be even older. I remember a huge ship was found in the desert and the whole of humanity is trying to make it work. There might be some alien race.
I remember a scene where this ship is starting to ascend and some elements, like starting columns, leave the ship.. And.. presumably this ship turns into a giant robot in interplanetary space (or it might be just my memory glitch).

Any thought?

Comment: if you're not sure about the giant robot part, the PC game Homeworld (1999) fits and had compelling cutscenes.  not sure if you'd mistake it for a full series though

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***[Super Dimension Fortress Macross](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0142183/)*** (1982–1983)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Dimension_Fortress_Macross):

> *Super Dimension Fortress Macross* (Japanese: 超時空要塞マクロス, Hepburn: *Chōjikū Yōsai Makurosu*, lit. "Super Spacetime Fortress Macross") is an anime television series from 1982. According to story creator Shoji Kawamori, it depicts "a love triangle against the backdrop of great battles" during the first Human-alien war. It is the first part of two franchises: The *Super Dimension* trilogy and *Macross* series.
>
> *Macross* (/məˈkrɒs/) features mechanical designs by Kazutaka Miyatake and Shoji Kawamori (both of Studio Nue) and character designs by Haruhiko Mikimoto of Artland. *Macross* also created one of the first anime idols Lynn Minmay, turning her voice actress Mari Iijima into an instant celebrity, and launching her musical career. Most of its animation (with edited content and revised dialogue) was adapted in the US for the first saga of *Robotech*.

From IMDB:

> An alien spaceship crash lands on Earth and her secrets lead to a desperate war against an alien enemy sent to retrieve the ship.

In the year 1999, a huge alien ship crash lands on a desert island on Earth, and humanity unites under a new global government to restore it to a flightworthy condition over the following decade. After the ship is restored and launched into space, it battles smaller alien vessels, and subsequently transforms into a giant robot-like form, as shown towards the end of episode 5, "[Transformation](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1054779/?ref_=ttep_ep5)."

> Captin Global has ordered the Macross to change to combat mode to fiend off attack waves sent by the Zentradi.

Comment: Thank you. So it wasn't a dream. That thing was for real. I should confess, that it looks not so fancy as my childhood memories :)